# Redirect or Forward maintaining the BindingResults

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am looking for a way to do a redirect or forward from one Controller request mapping to another.

The situation is that I have a Controller that has three stages: User inputs data -> Preview page -> Submit.  In the Preview request mapping I have the Model Attribute and its BindingResult.  If I have errors in the binding, I want to push the user back to the New form using a redirect, but when I do that Spring re-evaluates the ModelAttribute, and thusly re-creates the BindingResult.

Some code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "\new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApplicationUserCreated
public String formNew(
        @ModelAttribute("formBean") FormBean formBean,
        BindingResult bindingResults,
        Model uiModel) {
    // Do some stuff

    // Send the "new form" view
    return "new.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping("/preview", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ApplicationUserCreated
public String formPreview(
        @ModelAttribute("formBean") FormBean formBean,
        BindingResult bindingResults,
        Model uiModel) {
    // TODO: Validate the form
    if(bindingResults.hasErrors()) {
        // Redirect them back to the "New" form
        return "redirect:" + "/new";
    } else {
        return "preview.jsp";
    }
}
```

Please excuse any typos, as I had to try to simplify the code some.  I tried removing the BindingResults from the formNew() method, but when Preview redirects to New, it still seems to overwrite the BindingResults.  I also tried doing a "forward" instead, but same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just calling *formNew()* from *formPreview()* when I needed to send the user back to the new.jsp.  I don't get the redirect, so the URL in the browser shows as "/preview", but at least it's working and I feel like I am not wasting time duplicating code.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the BindingResult in Session or you can try to send that data with [Spring Flash Attributes](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-flash-attributes.html), if you have at least spring 3.1 .

** if ManagementMovesFormBean extends or implements you're FormBean, you should send that bean in flash attributes.

** by the way, to validate you're form, you should have added @Valid in front of  @ModelAttribute(".....

Don't forget that a BindingResult is assign to a single class, in you're example you have 2 methods with different expected objects, so those two BindingObjects are different

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using Spring 3.1, but rather 3.0.6.  And we don't use JSR 303 either, only the "validation" that occurs as a function of the Init Binder process.  So, basically if there is an Integer in the model object, and Spring can't figure out how to turn the user input into an Integer, it binds an error for type mismatch.  The rest of the validation is done manually.

Comment: ok, then you can add HttpSession as a parameter to each method. In #formPreview in case of errors, you can add the BindingResult to session, in #formNew you can verify if you have stored a bindingResult in session. How this sounds?

Comment: I was hoping Spring had some nifty built-in way to handle these scenarios, but I guess not.  What I ended up doing is just calling my formNew method directly from formPreview, passing in the BindingResults.  I don't get the redirected URL like I wanted, but at least I am not relying on storing and retrieving Spring generated objects in session.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the purpose of the preview page is but I would recommend performing validation on the same page and only when input is valid to proceed to preview using a redirect.